# Azure IOT EDGE Get resource properties from EGDE using c#

Tags: c#, azure, azure-iot-edge

I need to get resource from AZURE IOT EDGE using c#,
here is the link where I need to list all properties for this entity.
https//learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ext/azure-iot/iot/edge/deployment?view=azure-cli-latest#ext_azure_iot_az_iot_edge_deployment_list

Comment: This post has several problems.  Read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for guidance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use C# code to exec azure cli command.

***My test code is too simple, you can search `ProcessAsyncHelper` in github, then use to your project.***

In cmd tools.

[image]

By C# code, you need to `az login` first .

[image]

## Sample Code

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ProcessStartInfo startinfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
        startinfo.FileName = @"cmd.exe";
        Process process = new Process();
        process.StartInfo = startinfo;
        process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        process.Start();
        process.StandardInput.WriteLine("az iot edge deployment list --hub-name jasonp2testhub  --resource-group v-jasonp2");
        string line = string.Empty;
        
        while (!process.StandardOutput.EndOfStream)
        {
            line = process.StandardOutput.ReadLine();
            
            Console.WriteLine(line);
        }
        process.WaitForExit();
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```